# How long on average does it take for the ladybugs meet at the same vertex? - Discrete Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> We consider a regular pentagon which the vertices are numbered from
>   $1$ to $5$ in the direction of clockwise.  Initially (i.e. at time
>   $0$), two ladybugs are placed at the vertices $1$ and $3$. At each
>   next moment, each of ladybugs moves independently of the other, to one
>   of two adjacent corners with probability $½$ each two. How long on
>   average does it take for the ladybugs meet at the same vertex?

I think we have to consider the number of edges between the two ladybugs.

I have to prepare for an exam for the course of Stochastic Processes, and a part of the material bothers me enormously; essentially it is a problem resolution by **conditioning method**. Does someone could solve my problem and clearly explain each step (with schematisation if possible)? I tried, but I can not go very far in the problem. It should also say that my first course probability goes back more than three years; this may be part of why I have trouble on that kind of question.

Comment: What happens if they both go clockwise? Both go counterclockwise? Both go in opposite directions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game has three states $d\in\{0,1,2\}$, whereby $d$ denotes the shortest edge distance of the two bugs. I assume that the two bugs may use the same edge at the same time without disturbing each other.

Denote by $E_d$  the expected number of additional moves when the bugs are in state $d$. Obviously $E_0=0$. When the bugs are in state $1$ they  certainly will make a move. With probability ${3\over4}$ this move will end in state $1$ (necessitating $E_1$ further moves), and with probability ${1\over4}$ this move will end in state $2$ (necessitating $E_2$ further moves).  Arguing similarly when the bugs are in state $2$ one arrives at the system of equations
$$\eqalign{E_0&=0\cr E_1&=1+{3\over4}E_1+{1\over4}E_2 \cr E_2&=1+{1\over4}E_0+{1\over4}E_1+{1\over2}E_2\ .\cr}$$
This leads to $E_1=12$, $E_2=8$. It follows that the average length of the game is $8$.

Comment: Why do you add 1 for $E_1$ and $E_2$? Could you explain in details please? Thank for your answer BTW!